# Image size after resizing is greater than original image

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

After resizing the image size is greater than the original

**original image detail**

- Dimension `1680 x 1050`
- Size `553 KB`

**Resized image**

- Dimension `720 x 1280`
- Size `1.83 MB`

Method i am using

```
 bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap (bitmap, bitmapGapX, bitmapGapY,
                    deviceWidth, deviceHeight);
```

Is there any way to get compressed resized image. Right now iamge size is lot larger than the original image

Comment: how did you calculate 553 KB?

Comment: are you saving the resized image as a JPEG or PNG with Bitmap.compress()? You can adjust the quality setting downwards to get a smaller image

Comment: @Blackbelt If you check the image properties it shows 553KB

Comment: ok, but 1.83 MB is still the file size? how are you writing the 2nd bitmap on the disk?

Comment: @samgak Yes i'm saving images with `Bitmap.compress()` if I use JPEG the file size is little bit larger but if I use PNG then file size is extremely large

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes 1.83 MB is file size if I use PNG with `Bitmap.compress()`

Comment: If I recall correctly `png` is `lossless`. Was the original a `jpeg` ? What happens if you use JPEG as argument for compress in place of PNG?

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks, i used JPEG and the size now is considerably lesser than it was with PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation for [Bitmap.Compress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)), especially the second parameter (quality):

> **quality**   Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality. Some formats, like PNG which is lossless, will ignore the quality setting

Just use a lower quality setting to get a smaller file. It is quite possible for a resized image of a lower resolution to end up with a larger filesize than the original if the quality setting passed to Bitmap.compress() is large, and the original file was saved with a low quality setting.

So just try using a lower quality value e.g:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75 /*quality setting*/, outputStream);
```

Experiment with different quality settings until you find a good trade off between quality and file size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are resize image, but you can try with this method to reduce size. Run this method in background thread.

```
    public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

        Log.i(TAG, "qq imageUri = " + imageUri);
        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Log.i(TAG, "qq filePath = " + filePath);

        // getAxiomData( filePath);

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
        float maxHeight = 816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 612.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

        options.inSampleSize = utils.calculateInSampleSize(options,
                actualWidth, actualHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2,
                middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(
                        Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream uploadStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String filename = getFilename();
        try {
            // Store in folder
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);

            // Store in variable to upload
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                    uploadStream);
            byte[] byteArray = uploadStream.toByteArray();
            strBase64Img[imgCount] = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,
                    Base64.DEFAULT);

            // Show in layout
            finalBtmpImg[imgCount] = scaledBitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filename;
    }
```